# Django many-to-many relationship - database "None"?

Tags: django, python-3.5

I've been bashing my head on this problem for the past two hours or so and was wondering if someone could help me out. With this code:

```
ann = Announcement(**params)
ann.save()
# Push this announcement to each competitor's unread announcements queue
for competitor in Competitor.objects.all():
    competitor.unread_announcements.add(ann)
    #ann.competitor_set.add(competitor)
```

and the relevant model fields:

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField(blank=False)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
# ...
class Competitor(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    unread_announcements = models.ManyToManyField('Announcement')
```

When we get to the line adding the announcement to the queue, we get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/cam/Documents/Programming/web/pactf-web2/django/ctflex/management/commands/announce.py", line 40, in handle
    ann.competitor_set.add(competitor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 843, in add
    self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 963, in _add_items
    (obj, self.instance._state.db, obj._state.db)
ValueError: Cannot add "<Competitor: <Competitor #1 'cam'>>": instance is on database "None", value is on database "default"
```

All my research on the topic has shown that this error is caused when one or both of the relevant objects hasn't been saved in the database. However, in this case, I'm literally saving the announcement two lines beforehand, and the competitor object *already* lives in the database. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to post your settings file. It seems like something might be misconfigured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try omitting the id field of your Models. Since you're noting using the default id filed Django provided.

Comment: That seems to have been it. Altering that and changing some code around in my save() method seemed to do it.

Thanks!